SLURM --mem v. --mem-per-cpu for the purposes of running MATLAB in parallel
I'm learning how to submit batch jobs using SLURM, and I'm curious if there any difference between
#SBATCH -n 32
#SBATCH --mem==128G

v.
#SBATCH -n 32
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=4G

If I'm not mistaken, --mem-per-cpu=4G allows at most 4G of memory for each CPU. Is --mem==128G (coupled with -n 32) equivalent, or can it allow more than 4G of memory for each CPU, insofar as the total memory usage (across 32 CPUs) add up to 128G or less?
It's more of a conceptual question, so I'm not sure if I can really say I tried sth..
